# HD external error, file system seem damaged, and cannot look file with testdisk/photorec..... NTFS

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, ntfs

comment:
nb:hd=harddisk

my hd label kiomiiro-nii (upper case) size from box 750 Gb
but in propeties 698 gb.
i always use fix drive letter using M: for this hdexternal
(i dont have a backup because i don't have free space storage....)

now my hd is not detected at explorer, on usb safely remove just say usb mass storage without drive letter. and partition manager is say unallocated space.......

the last thing i remember when hd still can be read, it say
"failed to write m:/...[i forgot maybe mft or something....]"

then i use testdisk....

i can't change characteristic to L and E just *, P and D
but another hd with same merk just diferent size its using P[with analize to look current structure]

maybe this always showing showing and showing.....
partition: read error
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seem damaged.
read error at 0/17/1 (lba=1071)
0 D HPFS - NTFS 254705 79 58 341390 148 22 1392598837
HPFS - NTFS 254705 79 58 341390 148 22 1392598837
repair mft--->can't read NTFS MFT.

... etc

i already try file recovery use commercial file recovery and just get < 80% of my data[not this hd, other one] /data don't get all(where the other?) and folder structure is wrong.

after use testdisk 6.14, is not showing any partition, but when used 6.13 is showing, but label kiomiiro-nii not here and i write it to primary. after boot it's still can't read it and get prompt "format"...... no drive letter no, drive label

and i open 6.14 and 6.13 its still no drive label kiomiiro-nii, and can't open list file its say file system damage, and i go advance its say boot and backup sector is ok. and i open mft to is say can't read NTFS MFT.

================================

### here my note what i'm doing:

=========using 6.14=======

## disk /dev/sdb - 750 GB / 698 Gib - StoreJet Transcend

intel -> 
disk /dev/sdb - 750 GB / 698 Gib - StoreJet Transcend
CHS 91201 255 63 - sector size=512

analize ->
current partition structure:
(usually there is a list, but now no partition list here........)
partition: read error

quicksearch ->search under vista bla bla bla.....(Y)
(usually there is a list, but now no partition list here........)

Deeper search ->
disk /dev/sdb - 750 GB / 698 Gib - CHS 91201 255 63
analyse cylinder 1/91200: 00%
read error at 0/17/1 (lba=1071)
...meanwhile.....
invalid NTFS or EXFAT boot
0 D HPFS - NTFS 254705 79 58 341390 148 22 1392598837
HPFS - NTFS 254705 79 58 341390 148 22 1392598837
............final.............
the hardisk (750 gb/698 Gib) seem too small! (<2808 Gb/2615 GiB)
check the hardisk size:HD jumpers setting, BIOS detection...
[the hardisk size is right, why you say wrong(seem too small!)]

continue ->
no partition listed here................. -_-'

Deeper search ->[Again]

---

advance -> no partition available

=================================
---------------------------------------------------next
=========using 6.13=======

## disk /dev/sdb - 750 GB / 698 Gib - StoreJet Transcend

intel -> 
disk /dev/sdb - 750 GB / 698 Gib - CHS 91201 255 63

analize ->
current partition structure:
(usually there is a list, but now no partition list here........)
partition: read error

quicksearch ->search under vista bla bla bla.....(Y)
Disk /dev/sdb-750 GB/698 Gib - CHS 91201 255 63
partition start end size in sectors
* HPFS - NTFS 0 1 1 91200 254 63 1465144002

p ->(open list)
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.

quit ->[back to screen before]
Disk /dev/sdb-750 GB/698 Gib - CHS 91201 255 63
partition start end size in sectors
* HPFS - NTFS 0 1 1 91200 254 63 1465144002
[partition characteristik just * P D is can to use here, i can't change to L ]

Deeper search ->
disk /dev/sdb - 750 GB / 698 Gib - CHS 91201 255 63
analyse cylinder 1/91200: 00%
read error at 0/17/1 (lba=1071)
...meanwhile.....
invalid NTFS or EXFAT boot
0 D HPFS - NTFS 254705 79 58 341390 148 22 1392598837
HPFS - NTFS 254705 79 58 341390 148 22 1392598837
............final.............
the hardisk (750 gb/698 Gib) seem too small! (<2808 Gb/2615 GiB)
check the hardisk size:HD jumpers setting, BIOS detection...
[the hardisk size is right, why you say wrong(seem too small!)]

continue ->
partition start end size in sectors
* HPFS - NTFS 0 1 1 91200 254 63 1465144002

I change into P
(primary, because the choice show up just * D P)......
partition start end size in sectors

P HPFS - NTFS 0 1 1 91200 254 63 1465144002
write-> booting(hd still connect)

can't read files yet and become like this
1 P HPFS - NTFS 0 1 1 91200 254 63 1465144002

No partition is bootable

try again with 6.13

### and it say Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.

advance -> no partition available

=========================================== 
Next i use 6.14 again
and it say Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
advance say boot sector and back up sector is OK sector are identical
repair mft--->can't read NTFS MFT.

i use deep search in analize it run more than 30 hours but i waiting and the result is no partition available.hurt........

## please help me......................

last i use photorec, and can't list folder and file.......

===============================================
anyone know to solve my problem? i want get all my data, please.....
i searching how but not found anything until now

Comment: testdisk? vista? where is Ubuntu in all this?

Answer (score 0):

try r-studio. $50 for ntfs only. I had same issue as you and R-studio saw all my files 100%. Free download so you can tell if it works, pay to recover. Also try recuva and zar - zero assumption recovery.